# For loop for three arrays of viarables simultaneously

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, 3d

I want to loop through three lists of numbers simultaneously and do calculations on each combination of variables.
So I can later store all the calculated data in a 3-dimensional dataframe.

I've tried:

```
for (x,y,z) in [(x, y, z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]:
```

but this does not seem to work, it only performs the calculations for each value of x and y, but not z.

Any ideas how I can also loop through z at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: The single statement you provide works fine for me, given appropriate support.  Note that it's equivalent to the answer Pawel gives.

Answer (score 5):

How about using zip:

```
for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c):
    # Do something
```

## Update with concrete example

```
users = ['alex', 'john']
uids = [502, 501]
shells = ['bash', 'tcsh']

for user, uid, shell in zip(users, uids, shells):
    print('User: {}, UID: {}, Shell: {}'.format(user, uid, shell))
```

Output:

```
User: alex, UID: 502, Shell: bash
User: john, UID: 501, Shell: tcsh
```

Comment: I don't think he wants corresponding indexes. I think he wants all variations

Comment: This is how I understood the question. If the OP meant otherwise, then Pawel's solution should be used.

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for, ZIP takes the integer at the same place in each string. I would like every possible combination.

Comment: Have you looked at Pawel's solution?

Answer (score 1):

if you want all the combinations, use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
for x, y, z in product([1, 2], ['A', 'B'], [3, 4]):
    print(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the piece of code I tried to use actually did work. Just had to enumerate all my inputs.

`for (x,y,z) in [(x, y, z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]:`

It's possible to use this for dataframes with even more than 3 dimensions.
The itertools.product should also work for Multi-dimensional array for-loops.

Thanks for the responses everyone.